# Why do Bootstrap buttons stop working when put into a DIV?

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I've got 2 buttons that I am trying to position next to each other, centered on the page.  The easiest way to do this is put them in a div, but when I do this the buttons become unresponsive.  They loose their hover and clicking functionality.  I have tried changing the z-index of my background div, wrapper div and buttons but that didn't do anything.  Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load rest_framework %}
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/yeti/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'app/index.css' %}">
<title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>
{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        {{ message }}
    {%endfor%}
{%endif%}
{% verbatim %}
<div id="background"></div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <a href="/signup" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up Now!</a>
    <a href="" class="btn btn-info">Learn More</a>
</div>

<div id="topwrapper">
    <a href="/login">
        <div id="login">Log in</div>
    </a>
    <a href="/signup">
        <div id="signup">Sign Up</div>
    </a>
</div>
<h1>Catchy Interesting Hook.</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum stuff blah blah blah</p>
<h2>What is this website?</h2>
{% endverbatim %}
</body>
</html>
```

The links inside the topwrapper div work, but they are not bootstrap buttons.  NOTE:  The funny code inside the `{% %}` is Django stuff, I have installed various django-bootstrap plugins so maybe that is what is messing with my buttons?  But I am new to django so I don't really know how to go about investigating that.  And then my CSS is:

```
#background {
    background-color: #5f6273;
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border-width: 0px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: -30;
}
#wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 300px;
    background: none;
    width: 320px;
    display: inline;
    z-index: -1;
}
#topwrapper {
    width: 300px;
    display: inline;
    background-color: none;
    margin: auto;
    height: 100px;
    margin-right: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    padding: 20px;
}
#login {
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-color: #ffffff;
    height: 30px;
    width: 140px;
    left: 30%;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    z-index: 30;
}
#signup {
    left: -50%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    height: 30px;
    width: 70px;
    z-index: 30;
    margin: auto;
}
.btn-primary {
    float: left;
    margin-left: auto;
    z-index: 31;
}
.btn-info {
    float: right;
    margin-right: auto;
    z-index: 31;
}
h1 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-top: 160px;
}
h2 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000000;
    padding-top: 275px;
    z-index: 30;
}
p {
    font-family: serif;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-top: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I kept all of your css the same, but changed just a little in the html while removing the django stuff...and the links are working. Try adding your django code to this:

```
<body>
    <div id="background"></div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <button class="btn btn-primary"><a href="/signup">Sign Up Now!</a></button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary"><a href="/login">Learn More</a></button>
    </div>

    <div id="topwrapper">
        <a href="/login">
            <div id="login">Log in</div>
        </a>
        <a href="/signup">
            <div id="signup">Sign Up</div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <h1>Catchy Interesting Hook.</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum stuff blah blah blah</p>
    <h2>What is this website?</h2>
</body>
```

Comment: That did some funny things to the buttons, they are clickable now but all the positioning was lost (they are just in the top left corner) and the text on the buttons only appears when you hover over it.  Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a plunkr?